# CoreData Fetch Predicate for unrelated entities

Tags: core-data, ios5, nspredicate

I am having trouble to do a CoreData fetch request for unrelated entities. Lets assume I have an object model with 3 entities: `Message`, `User` and `Advisor`.

I want this 3 objects to be unrelated to each other. So a `Message` does have an attribute `senderEmail` and `receiverEmail` whilst `User` and `Advisor` do have the attribute `email`.
But again, there is no further relationship between those objects.
I now want for example to fetch the latest (newst) `Message` by an advisor or by a user. But how should I do this fetch predicate since the objects are not connected?

Is this even possible within one Fetch Request or do I need to fetch each objects separately into an array and then make further operations to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander,

if those entities are not related each other you need to excecute different fetch requests to grab your data.

So, for example, you could grab the latest `Message` setting up a request like the following:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"senderEmail == %@", grabbedEmail];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"insertionDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

NSFetchRequest *messageFetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[messageFetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext]];
[messageFetch setPredicate:predicate];
[messageFetch setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[messageFetch setFetchLimit:1];
```

To retrieve the `grabbedEmail` (if you don't have it) you need to set up a request with a specific predicate. The same could be applied for the receiver email. For example.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userId == %@", @"someUserId"];

NSFetchRequest* userFetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[userFetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:yourContext]];
[userFetch setPredicate:predicate];
[userFetch setFetchLimit:1];

NSArray* userResults = [userFetch executeFetchRequest:&error];

User* retrievedUser = (User*)[userResults objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* grabbedEmail = [retrievedUser email];
```

To sort by date you could simply add to `Message` enitity an attribute called `insertionDate` (of type `NSDate`) that allows you to order by date.

When you execute the request

```
NSArray* results = [messageFetch executeFetchRequest:&error];
```

the array `results` will contain the (only) `Message` element you are looking for.

Why do you need to maintain separate those entities?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! I need to maintain those entities separately because my model consists out of many more entities than the three above. I do not want to have a huge meshed model with relationships between all entities. So I thought it might be better to have some relationships modelled as fetched properties...